# Redirect www to non-www on https site using mod rewrite, VirtualHost, and/or Directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

This is my first post to StackOverflow, so please bear with me......

I'm trying to redirect www.example.com to https://example.com.  I've looked at quite a few solutions on StackOverflow and other forum sites, but I can't seem to get anything to work.  Here are a few of the other StackOverflow pages I've looked at:

[Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

[apache redirect from non www to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)

[Redirect Non-WWW to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379994/redirect-non-www-to-www)

My SSL cert lists both example.com and www.example.com.  Here is the code in my apache2.conf file that I've been trying to add the redirect:

```
<Directory /home/tim/examplepath>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sort-url.php?rt=$1
</Directory>

<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:12345>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com/ 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:80>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:123>
   ServerName example.com
   DocumentRoot /home/tim/examplepath/
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/sf_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like everything to redirect to https://example.com/sort-url.php?rt=$1 where I can then determine which page to show based on the variable $1.

Can someone please tell what I need to do?  ServerAlias in the  and the 301 redirect inside of the  haven't worked for me.

Thank you in advance!

Tim

Comment: This might help (although it is from https to http): [Apache mod rewrite https to http only for a specific URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103321/apache-mod-rewrite-https-to-http-only-for-a-specific-url)

Comment: I'm not sure what to add or do to my code from that.  My knowledge of mod rewrite is very limited....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a CNAME to my DNS records on my Rackspace account.  The CNAME is "www.highschoolclothing.com".

Thank you everyone for your help though!

Comment: Ahh, I kind of assumed your DNS records where up to date. Good thing you found it. You can accept your own answer btw. :-)

Comment: Thanks Qben.  StackOverflow wouldn't let me accept my own answer for 6 hours, but I'm able to now!  :)  I thought my DNS records were good, too, based on what my SSL check showed.  I think I misunderstood a few things (this is my first time setting up a server).  I didn't know CNAME could be used for the www issue, since all the examples I saw were a little different.  I really do appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

If you want **EVERYTHING** to end up in `example.com` you could make it your [_default_](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#default) site. I think you could do it like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
   Redirect permanent / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:123>
   ServerName example.com
   DocumentRoot /home/tim/examplepath/
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/sf_bundle.crt

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   # Check is HTTPS is used
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/sort-url.php?rt=$1 [R=301,L]

   # If we have not specified a file to access, redirect to sort-url.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sort-url.php?rt=$1
</VirtualHost>
```

I must admit this is untested, and I am a bit unsure if you need a `VirtualHost` for non-SSL connections that redirect to the SSL one.

**EDIT**
Changed so that the default host just forward to `https://example.com` to make sure the correct hostname is used.

Comment: Thank you Qben.  It didn't like the "RewriteBase /" in the VirtualHost (says only in directory).  Are you suggesting I don't need a <directory>?  Also, is there supposed to be an "=" in "%{HTTPS} =off"?  I'm still troubled by this problem.  Will post if I find a fix...

Comment: I would say that `RewriteBase` in this case can be removed since it's relative to `DocumentRoot`. Yes, it should say `=off` since you want to do the rewrite if HTTPS is not enabled. Since your `DocumentRoot` is the same path as your `Directory` you should be able to skip it. Basically I moved your stuff from `Directory` into the `VirtualHost`. Could you explain what happen when you access `www.example.com`?

Comment: When I try to access www.example.com, it takes me here:  http://search.dnsassist.verizon.net/

Comment: I tried the code you provided above.  When I restarted apache, it informed me that a virtualhost did not exist for *.80.  Once I added back a virtualhost for port 80, the site directed me to a "Bad Request" page...  Any ideas?  I'm completely stumped on this one.

Comment: You seem to be using ip based virtual hosts instead of name based. What ports do you have `Listen` statements for?